# Why toString method won't get the selected item in JComboBox?

Tags: java

I bind my values from database to JComboBox using ArrayList and converted each array using StringBuilder because StringBuilder accepts any data types so I think this is the most efficient way.

```
while(rs.next())
{
        departmentId = rs.getInt(1);
        departmentTypeList = rs.getString(2);

        ArrayList<DepartmentList> listDepartment = new ArrayList<DepartmentList>();

        listDepartment.add(new DepartmentList(departmentId,departmentTypeList));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(DepartmentList s : listDepartment)
        {
           builder.append(s);
        }
       cbDepartmentType.addItem(builder.toString());
}

private class DepartmentList
{
    private int id;
    private String department;

    private DepartmentList(int id,String department)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.department = department;
    }

    private int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() //Converting to String the (departmentId,departmentTypeList)
    {
        return department;
    }
}
```

I added a listener on my JComboBox to listen what item is selected. I already converted my class to Object but when I click the JComboBox it gives me a exception `java.lang.String` Any ways to solve this problem?

```
if(e.getSource() == cbDepartmentType)
{
   DepartmentList item = (DepartmentList) cbDepartmentType.getSelectedItem();
   System.out.println("id "+(item.getId()));
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to position.AddPosition$DepartmentList
at position.AddPosition$ItemHandler.actionPerformed(AddPosition.java:295)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:586)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
```

Update:

```
while(rs.next())
{
   departmentId = rs.getInt(1);
   departmentTypeList = rs.getString(2);

   ArrayList<DepartmentList> listDepartment = new ArrayList<DepartmentList>();
   listDepartment.add(new DepartmentList(departmentId,departmentTypeList));
   cbDepartmentType.addItem(listDepartment.toString());
}
```

Comment: post full stacktrace please

Comment: Do you mean you get a `ClassCastException` because `cbDepartmentType.getSelectedItem()` returns a `String`, which you are trying to cast to a `DepartmentList`? A `String` is not a `DepartmentList`, so you cannot cast it.

Comment: First, add the stack trace of this exception. Then, why do you want to concatenate all the departement into one item off the combobox ? Since you are doing that into the loop to read the resultset ...

Comment: your while loop looks weird..you have id and typelist, you are crating object and then adding to list and then getting from the list as object and adding to string builder then to Jcombobox

Comment: The issue is that you are giving object of DepartmentList to the builder

Comment: @AnoopLL, `StringBuilder.append(Object)` will be used, this will use `Object.toString()`.

Comment: You are adding String an not Department instance to the combobox, so getSelectedItem will return a String. You can add the departement instance directly has an item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `String` to the `Combobox`

```
cbDepartmentType.addItem(builder.toString());
```

And you try to cast the selected item into a `DepartementList`

```
DepartmentList item = (DepartmentList) cbDepartmentType.getSelectedItem();
```

But you get a String. So something like this is try to run.

```
DepartmentList item = (DepartmentList) "A string";
```

You can add `DepartmentList` to the comboxbox directly.

```
cbDepartmentType.addItem(departement);
```

This will use the implementation of `toString()` of DepartementList to print the text in the component.

With this, the selectedItem will be an instance of DepartementList.

Here is the official tutorial of [How to use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

## EDIT :

Your code should look like :

```
while(rs.next())
{
        departmentId = rs.getInt(1);
        departmentTypeList = rs.getString(2);

        DepartmentList dep = new DepartmentList(departmentId,departmentTypeList); //Create a department
       cbDepartmentType.addItem(dep ); //insert into the combo
}
```

In your original code, you were using a List to store the instance then recover this instance to parse it into a StringBuilder then insert this represention (a String) into the combobox.

My logic

> Department -> Combobox

Yours

> List > Departemnt > StringBuilder > Combobox

Try to understand the while loop you had, you will see this was not logic at all.

Comment: I add the ArrayList into my JComboBox directly using `cbDepartmentType.addItem(listDepartment.toString());`. But still giving me the same exception when selecting an item

Comment: @Francisunoxx That's not adding an ArrayList, that's adding its **string representation**, as the answer tells you. You are adding a string, you can't convert it back to a different object.

Comment: You need to add each item,. The item you pass will be the one you will retrieve as the selected item. Stay consistent with the type used. Use the loop you use to create the String with the StringBuilder. Check the link had just add if you need more help

Comment: @AxelH Can you elaborate your answer please? I didn't get the department variable. Where did It came from?

Comment: @AxelH `builder.append(String)` is already converted to String. After that adding the (String) in the JComboBox. `cbDepartmentType.addItem(String.valueOf(String));`. Still gave me a exception? Why?

Comment: @Francisunoxx You don't undestand. A combobox is just a visual List. If you add `String` into this List, you will get `String` in return. `department` is an instance of `departmentList` that you create from your resultset, this is what you want to put into the Combobox. So do it. See my edit

Comment: @AxelH Sorry I think to much and having a many conversion. I added `toString()` inside `addItem` parameter to convert it. But casting getSelectedItem to DepartmentList part giving me a exception. `DepartmentList item =  (DepartmentList) cbDepartmentType.getSelectedItem();`

Comment: @Francisunoxx, **Don't convert into String with `toString()`**, you are trying to get a `DepartmentList` instance so add a `DepartmentList` instance NOT A STRING...

Comment: @AxelH Because what it say here. `DepartmentList cannot be converted to String` that's why.

Comment: @Francisunoxx JCombobox are Generic. This meaning you probably write `JCombobox<String>` somewhere telling the class it will work with `String`. Replace that by `JCombobox<DepatementList>` to specifiy this will use this type of data.

Comment: @AxelH I already understand what you said. Yes the error gone when replacing `JComboBox<DepartmentList>` but adding `DepartmentList` instance in JComboBox `cbDepartmentType.addItem(dep);` won't load the list of items.

Comment: @Francisunoxx `won't load the list of items`, what is that even mean ? This will add every instance into the combobox and give you the opportunity to recover these instance. If this is not working, at least explain why ... You had a ClassCastException that I had corrected with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128325/discussion-between-axelh-and-francisunoxx).

Comment: I mean that the String that I returned using `toString()` method won't load the items that contains department name. But the ClassCastException already gone. :)